# how to track the memory usage in visual studio 2017 (c++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

i have an error says "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED" so i want to know how to get the memory locations of all the program .

[image: the error]

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're wanting the tool to tell you. Do you want to know the memory locations that were accessed by your program, or the lines of code that tried to write to that section of memory?  
Also, put an exclamation mark (`!`) in front of your image link to directly embed it in the question, eg `![alt text][1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose heap corruption errors on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413066/how-do-i-diagnose-heap-corruption-errors-on-windows)

Comment: SmartBear AQTime is a pretty good profiling tool.

Comment: i want to know the memory locations that were accessed by the program @ZoeyHewll

Answer (score 0):

If the program is reliable at always allocation #150 then you can call [_CrtSetBreakAlloc(150)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetbreakalloc) to break on the 150th allocation.  Alternatively, you can slow your program down and make the debug heap more accurate at reporting issues by calling  [_CrtSetDbgFlag(  _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetdbgflag) which turns on the heap checking for all allocations and frees.

Finally you could use Application Verifier for release builds of your product to find issues. Application Verifier download is [Microsoft : here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/index)